# Pyomo Error: TypeError: 'MonomialTermExpression' object is not iterable

Tags: pyomo

I keep getting this error - "TypeError: 'MonomialTermExpression' object is not iterable" - from the constraint component below of my AbstractModel Construction. However, I do not seem to understand this error and how to fix it. I shall be glad if anyone on this platform could point me in the right direction.

Thank you.

```
model.Q = pyo.Var(initialize=0.000001, within=pyo.PercentFraction, name='Variable for MinMax MOMP')

def wt_rule1(model,i,j):
    for (i,j), val in model.w.extract_values().items():
        return (val*(sum(model.d[i,j]*model.x[i,j])-291)/291.0) <= model.Q
model.distConst = pyo.Constraint(model.A,rule=wt_rule1)
```

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with this many times, I have realized that re-constructing the constraint object as follows worked:

```
def wt_rule1(model,i,j):
    for (i,j), val in model.w.extract_values().items():
        return  (val*(sum(model.d[i,j]*model.x[i,j] for i in model.I for j in model.J)-291)/291) <= model.Q
model.distConst = pyo.Constraint(model.A, rule=wt_rule1)
```